# Cannot authenticate with Cloudflare via terraform provider

Tags: terraform, cloudflare

I'm trying to follow terraform documentation, but for some reason I'm getting error while trying to authenticate with my Cloudlfare account from within terraform (with terragrunt).

So my config is:

```
locals {
  cloudflare_api_token = get_env("CLOUDFLARE_API_TOKEN")
  cloudflare_email = get_env("CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL")
}

terraform {
  source = "my source dir"
}

generate "versions" {
  path      = "versions.tf"
  if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  contents  = <<EOF
    terraform {
      required_providers {
        cloudflare = {
          source = "cloudflare/cloudflare"
          version = "~> 3.0"
        }
      }
    }
EOF
}

generate "provider" {
  path = "provider.tf"
  if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  contents = <<EOF
    provider "cloudflare" {
       email = "${local.cloudflare_email}"
       api_token = "${local.cloudflare_api_token}"
    }
EOF
}
```

Now, the error is:

```
"email": all of `api_key,email` must be specified
```

I'm a bit confused as I think I actually don't need to use `api_key` if I'm using `api_token`. Also `api_key` seems to be deprecated.
Btw, terraform configs are created correctly (from terragrunt configs).
How can I authenticate?

Comment: Which terraform version are you using?

Comment: Terraform version is: 1.2.6

Comment: Ok, that should be good. Why don't you use the locals you defined for `email` and `api_token` if that's possible at all?

Comment: Sorry, I wrongly copied it. But I do use them. I will change the question content

Comment: And those env vars are definitely there? If you run `env` do they show up in the list?

Comment: yes, they are for 100% there

Comment: And if you were to omit any configuration from `provider "cloudflare"`, would that work?

Comment: It says: Provider "registry.terraform.io/cloudflare/cloudflare" requires explicit
configuration. Add a provider block to the root module and configure the
provider's required arguments as described in the provider documentation.

Comment: Did you run `terragrunt init` prior to anything else?

Comment: I've found the issue, I had set environment variables (both token and email) and it had precedence over setting within the config. Sorry for that! And thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `provider.email` ( your `email = "${local.cloudflare_email}"`), since you don't need it when using an API token.

From [v3.19.0 introduces breaking change around configuration](https://github.com/cloudflare/terraform-provider-cloudflare/issues/1768#issuecomment-1182740447)

> you only need email when defining api_key.

---

I would call this a bug  in `terraform-provider-cloudflare`, in that it gives you a bad error message.

Answer (score 0):

email or variable CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL required when using api_key. Conflicts with api_token.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33456518)